# QuerySet using only() to fetch reference with no deferring

Tags: django, django-queryset, deferred

Consider the following:

```
objs1 = MyModel.objects.filter(field1='1').only('foreign_key1','field2')
objs2 = MyModel.objects.filter(field1='2').only('foreign_key1','field2')

for o1 in objs1:
    matches = [o2 for o2 in objs2 if o1.foreign_key1==o2.foreign_key1]
    print len(matches)
```

[`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) makes all the other fields deferred. However AFAICT, although I requested `foreign_key1` not to be deferred, it is! and the list comprehension takes a very long while due to the db being hit twice per itteration.

I also tried `foreign_key1__id` in the querysets but it didn't help. How can I not deffer the foreign key while still using `only()`?

Comment: Please don't suggest joins, the actual code is more complicated and I cannot use joins

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was not in the `only()` at all. As far as I can tell `only()` doesn't fetch related models, even if you give it the foreign key field. To fetch related models you need [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related). Furthermore, notice that if `null=True` for the `ForeignKey`, you also need to give `select_related()` the specific foreign key field such as follows:

```
.select_related('foreign_key1')
```

the following is enough as well in my case:

```
.select_related('foreign_key1__id')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
o1.foreign_key1_id==o2.foreign_key1_id
```

it should help.

only('xxxx_id') makes no sense.